# Fill multiarray (matrix) in C using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, matrix

If you want to fill a matrix in C, you can use index, like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

    char m[20][30];

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    while(i <= 20){
        j=0;
        while(j <= 30){

            m[i][j] = 's';
            printf("%c", m[i][j]);
            j++;

        }
        printf("\n");
        i++;
    }
}
```

but how can I do this with pointers?

Comment: first of all this is getting out of bounds... `i <= 20` should be `i < 20` and `j <= 30` should be `j < 30`

Comment: Depends, you mean that you want to stock pointers in your matrix or to access your matrix with pointers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case:

To use a pointer:

```
char m[20][30];
char *ptr; // Your pointer 
ptr=m; // point ptr to the location where m points to
```

Now, replace

```
m[i][j] = 's';
printf("%c", m[i][j]);
```

with

```
*((char *)ptr + (i * 30) + j) = 's';
    printf("%c", *((char *)ptr + (i * 30) + j));
```

---

**Why this works?**

**For 1-D array:**

```
 int a[10];
```

You can access it like:

```
a[1]; //Say the 2nd element
```

So, in terms of pointers, this is equivalent to:

```
*((int*)a+1).
```

**For 2-D arrays:**

```
int b[NO_OF_ROWS][NO_OF_COLUMNS];
```

In generalized form, assume any elment:

```
b[r][c]; // let r < NO_OF_ROWS, c < NO_OF_COLUMNS be any index
```

is equivalent to

```
*((int *)b + r * NO_OF_COLUMNS  + c);
```

Comment: Second element, you mean.

Comment: @Geovanny Méndez Marín: I have update my answer, see if this helps

Comment: `(int *)`? type of `m` is `char[][30]`. Isn't `(char *)` correct?

Comment: In addtion, the casting is unnecessary. just `*(m + i * 30 + j)` is okay.

Comment: Yes that is unnecessary.. just that it helps to understand better.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the reason of using pointers instead `[]` operator is it's a bit faster (in theory, anyway)... In this case, I think you want this..

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char m[20][30];

    char (*ptr1)[30];
    char *ptr2;

    for (ptr1 = m; ptr1 < m + sizeof(m) / sizeof(m[0]); ptr1++)
    {
        for (ptr2 = *ptr1; ptr2 < *ptr1 + sizeof(*ptr1) / sizeof((*ptr1)[0]); ptr2++)
        {
            *ptr2 = 's';
            printf("%c", *ptr2);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really epic I will take it